# I received The Overflow #51 twice, instead of #52

Tags: bug, email, the-overflow

I just wanted to report that I received last week's edition of The Overflow (#51) again today. I guess that you meant to send out edition #52 today.

<sub>Sorry for the short Q, but there's really nothing more to say, except that I enjoy reading The Overflow. Keep up the good work!</sub>

---

**Update:** Just received #52 as well (22 minutes after #51), so someone noticed and fixed it, thanks! I'll leave the question open, anyways, because <strike>we are nosy and want to know what went wrong</strike> such mishaps often have interesting root causes, and we are all developers who are eager to learn.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412069/8333641