# Was a duplicate of the Overflow #93 (from September 30th) sent on October 7th to all subscribers?

Tags: bug, email, newsletter, the-overflow

I just received Issue #93 of The Overflow (Stack Overflow's newsletter). This is the same issue I received 7 days ago.

[image]

<sup>(my timezone is CEST = GMT+2)</sup>

Did this affect (all) other subscribers? Will there still be an Issue #94 this week?

---

For the record, this has happened to [at least one user 9 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403761/8333641)

---

**Update** The week is over, and I haven't received Issue #94. I don't know if issue #94 has just *not been issued* at this point, or whether just a handful of users have received a duplicate instead of the new one.

Comment: I got the duplicate too. I was reading through it and I was like 'all of this feels vaguely familiar for some reason??' and then checked my inbox and there was another #93 from last week.